# How to do an efficient priority update in STL priority_queue?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I have a priority_queue of some object:

```
typedef priority_queue<Object> Queue;
Queue queue;
```

From time to time, the priority of one of the objects may change - I need to be able to update the priority of that object in the queue in an efficient way. Currently I am using this method which works but seems inefficient:

```
Queue newQueue;
while (!queue.empty())
{
  Object obj=queue.top();
  queue.pop();

  if (priorityHasChanged(obj))
    newQueue.push_back(Object(new_priority));
  else
    newQueue.push_back(obj);
}

newQueue.swap(queue); // this only works because I actually subclassed the priority_queue
                 // class and exposed a swap method that swaps in the container
```

I implemented it this way because I was in kind of a hurry at the time and this was the quickest thing I could do that I could be sure it would work ok. There has to be a better way than this though. Really what I want is a way to either:

- extract out the instance with the changed priority and insert a new one with the new priority value
- update the instance with the changed priority and then update the queue so that it is correctly sorted

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are out of luck with standard priority queue because you can't get at the underlying deque/vector/list or whatever. You need to implement your own - it's not that hard.

Comment: That's not correct -- the standard priority queue stores the container as protected member `c` (see [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)). You can derive from the priority queue and access the container in the derived class.

Comment: @user283145 sure you can get access to the underlying heap with `c` but since you can't find the index of a key in O(logn), you can't do a priority update in O(lgn) which is really the unfortunate part.

Answer (score 70):

I can suggest 2 choices to solve the problem, although neither performs a real update.

1. Use the `priority_queue` and push element each time you would like to update it. Accept the fact that you will have useless entries in the queue. When popping the top value, check if it contains the up-to-date value. If not, ignore it and pop the next.

   This way you delay the removal of the updated element until it comes to the top. I noticed this approach being used by top programmers realizing Dijkstra algorithm.
2. Use `set`. It is also sorted so you are able to extract the greatest element in logarithmic time. You are also able to remove the outdated element before inserting it again. So still no update operation possible, but removal and reinsertion is doable.

Seems like the complexity of both approaches is the same.

Comment: "I noticed this approach being used by top programmers realizing Dijkstra algorithm." It'd have been a lot clearer if the programmers mentioned this fact. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Usually the data in the queue is redundant. So you can compare the value from the queue with the value in another data object, a table maybe. If the value is different, it should be discarded.

Comment: For the first way, I can't understand the word he used, but article here clarify what he really meant by "push element each time you would like to update" : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-using-priority_queue-stl/

Comment: Complexity is not the same. Operations on `priority_queue` with n actual items and m outdated items would take O(log (n + m)) versus O(log n).

Comment: I found that the priority_queue approach is much faster in practice, at least on larger datasets

Answer (score 7):

I have implemented a high-performance updatable priority queue and made it available [on github](https://github.com/Ten0/updatable_priority_queue).

This is how you would typically use it :

```
better_priority_queue::updatable_priority_queue<int,int> pQ;
pQ.push(0, 30);   // or pQ.set(0, 30)
pQ.push(1, 20);
pQ.push(2, 10);

pQ.update(2, 25); // or pQ.set(2, 25)

while(!pQ.empty())
    std::cout << pQ.pop_value().key << ' ';

// Outputs: 0 2 1
```

To complement Jarekczek's answer, if indeed both the `set` and "pure heap with useless entries" approaches have the same complexity, the `stl::set` version typically performs much slower than the `stl::priority_queue` version due to the fact that it is implemented with red-black trees that only guarantee their depth to be lower than 2*log_2(n_elements) and require regular updates, while `stl::priority_queue` is an as pure and fast binary heap as possible. This is why it is typically used when implementing Dijkstra.

The set approach may however be faster when making a lot of updates on few base nodes. This is also where using my library would bring you the most improvement.

Answer (score 5):

The appropriate data structure is called "Fibonacci Heap".
But you need to implement it yourself.
Insert/Updates are O(1)
ExtractMin is O(logn)

Comment: Binary Heap can also be tweaked to allow updates. It would be O(log n), but in practice Binary Heap is usually much more performant than Fibonacci Heap because it is simpler and more cache efficient.

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward way to do this with STL (that I know) is to remove the entry, update its priority and then reinsert it.  Doing this is quite slow using std::priority_queue, however you can do the same thing with std::set.  Unfortunately you have to be careful to not change the priority of an object when it is in the set.

I have implemented a mutable_priority_queue class based gluing together an std::multimap (for priority to value mapping) and an std::map (for value to priority mapping) that allows you to insert/remove items as well as update existing values in logarithmic time.  You can get the code and an example of how to use it [here](http://jamesgregson.blogspot.com/2010/02/updateable-priority-queue.html)

Comment: You cannot remove an entry at a random position in a stl priority queue - you can only access the top element.

Comment: @James: Thanks for the code. Here are some suggestions: (1) The template definition for mutable_priority_queue is evidently (priority, key), however, the insert statement is (key, priority). These should be consistent, preferably with both being (key, priority). The iterator should likewise have 'first' being the key and 'second' being the priority. (2) You should provide a getPriority(const key) to get the current priority. This is a common requirement for algorithms where you need to get the priority for an item that's not necessarily at the top in order to bump the priority up or down.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at `replace_if` with an example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace_if.html).

Comment: Sorry this is not usable, the priority_queue class does not have random access (or any other type of) iterators. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot update value in priority_queue. priority_queue does not offer such interface.

I think you'd better use `set` as Jarekczek said or use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811888/4785256)(using make_heap).