# How to tell a std::priority_queue to refresh its ordering?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I have a priority queue of pointers to a `struct city`. I modify the objects pointed by these pointers outside the priority queue, and want to tell the priority queue to "reorder" itself according to the new values.

What should I do?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct city {
    int data;
    city *previous;
};

struct Compare {
    bool operator() ( city *lhs, city *rhs )
    {
        return ( ( lhs -> data ) >= ( rhs -> data ) );
    }
};

typedef priority_queue< city *, vector< city * >, Compare > pqueue;

int main()
{
    pqueue cities;

    city *city1 = new city;
    city1 -> data = 5;
    city1 -> previous = NULL;
    cities.push( city1 );

    city *city2 = new city;
    city2 -> data = 3;
    city2 -> previous = NULL;
    cities.push( city2 );

    city1 -> data = 2;
    // Now how do I tell my priority_queue to reorder itself so that city1 is at the top now?

    cout << ( cities.top() -> data ) << "\n";
    // 3 is printed :(

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem I got! According to the documentation in cppreference.com, it should reorder the queue once we call the push function. It takes me months to find this bug...

I ended up using the make_heap and push_heap function to work. but I would still like to switch back to priority_queue since this is a cleaner solution!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a bit hackish, but nothing illegal about it, and it gets the job done.

```
std::make_heap(const_cast<city**>(&cities.top()),
               const_cast<city**>(&cities.top()) + cities.size(),
               Compare());
```

**Update**:

Do not use this hack if:

- The underlying container is not `vector`.
- The `Compare` functor has behavior that would cause your external copy to order differently than the copy of `Compare` stored inside the `priority_queue`.
- You don't fully understand what these warnings mean.

You can always write your own container adaptor which wraps the heap algorithms.  `priority_queue` is nothing but a simple wrapper around `make/push/pop_heap`.

Comment: `std::priority_queue` does not guarantee it's elements are contiguous unless the underlying container provides that guarantee.

Comment: Agreed.  That's part of the "hackishness".  The underlying container in this example is vector which guarantees a contiguous buffer.  Another part of the "hackishness" is that the comparator should be stateless.  And then there's the const_cast which will scare many code reviewers off, but actually do exactly the right thing in this example.  This example works.  But don't change the container to deque, don't supply a stateful comparator, and don't abuse it by calling make_heap "too often", lest the performance will degrade.  Used judiciously, this hack just works.

Comment: This worked in my case, thanks :).
For future reference, what do you mean by a stateful comparator? Sorry if the question is stupid.

Comment: I'm not sure `priority_queue` is even guaranteed to interoperate with `make_heap` and friends. Hacky, indeed.

Comment: @Skkard:  I've updated my answer with warnings about the sharp edges of this hack.  I've replaced the words "stateful comparator" with bullet two above, which is hopefully clear.

Comment: @larsmans:  `priority_queue` is specified to call `make/push/pop_heap`.

Comment: @Howard Hinnant - Thanks. I got it now. :)

Comment: This is quiet the hack, but please do tell me the runtime is O(log(n))...It seems as though it is linear, as opposed to truly being logarithmic.

Answer (score 8):

Based on http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/priority_queue.html it does not look like there is a way to do that, without emptying and re-inserting.

If you are willing to move away from priority_queue (but still want a heap), then you can use a vector, along with the [make_heap](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/make_heap.html), [push_heap](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/push_heap.html) and [pop_heap](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/pop_heap.html). See the Notes section in the page for [priority_queue](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/priority_queue.html).

Comment: I was about to suggest `make_heap` and friends, but couldn't work out the algorithm. How does it work?

Comment: @lars: The make_heap/push_heap/pop_heap pages have examples and description on how to use them. (Or were you interested in the internals?).

Comment: @Moron: I understand how those functions work. Are you saying the OP should call `make_heap` after every update?

Comment: @lars: If the compare function changes (or the pointed to data changes), then yes. make_heap has to be called. It could be inefficient if the updates are frequent. If only there was a change_key (which I could not find)... Not sure how make_heap deals with data which is already an 'almost heap'. Maybe it won't be too inefficient after all...

Answer (score 8):

If you need to keep an ordered collection you may consider the following solution: Use `std::set` and to update values remove the item, update its value and place it back into the set. This will give you O(log n) complexity for updating one item, which is the best you can in a usual heap structure (Assuming you had access to its internals to mass with the sift-up sift-down procedures).
The only downside to `std::set` will be the time for initializing a set with n items. (O(n log n) instead of O(n)).

Comment: But in a set I can't have two elements with the same data, can I? :(

Comment: +1 for this solution, which is much more efficient than Moron's. @Skkard: in an `std::multiset`, you can.

Comment: btw, +1 for this :-) I presume any balanced binary tree would do too (which is what I am guessing std:set is implemented as). Does std::set/multiset guarantee O(log n) insert/delete and access to max/min?

Comment: @lars: I deleted my earlier comment as I misread this answer. You are right, this is likely better.

Comment: @Moron: `std::set` and `multiset` guarantee O(lg n) insert/delete as well as max *and* min (via `begin` and `rbegin`), which makes them pretty good, but not excellent, double-ended priority queues.

Comment: @lars: And if getting O(1) max/min is an absolute requirement (like a heap), one can cache it...

Comment: This solution costs an allocation + deallocation per modification.  Without the 2009-09-19 recommendation to LWG 839: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#839 , the cost of this can be too much depending on the application.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but I wasn't fully satisfied with any of the answers when I wanted to do this myself. There is no need for any hacks. `std::priority_queue` contains all the machinery to do this legally and idiomatically.

`std::priority_queue` has two very helpful data members, `c` (the underlying container) and `comp` (the comparison predicate).

Equally helpfully, the standard mandates that the `Container` template type must be a model of `SequenceContainer` who's iterators are models of `RandomAccessIterator`.

This is helpful because the `Iter` argument type of `std::make_heap` have the same `RandomAccessIterator` model requirement.

This is a longwinded way of saying that `std::priority_queue` is a wrapper around a heap and that therefore `std::make_heap(std::begin(c), std::end(c), comp)` must be a valid expression.

The 'bad' news is that `c` and `comp` are protected. This is actually good news for two reasons:

1. You can't destroy the heap accidentally.
2. If you derive from `std::priority_queue` you can modify the heap intentionally.

So the trick is to derive your priority queue from `std::priority_queue`, in a member function, mutate the internal heap `c` any way you like and then call `std::make_heap(std::begin(c), std::end(c), comp);` to turn it back into a valid heap.

> Is it not, generally, a bad idea to inherit from STL containers

Well, yes, but...

There are two reasons that this could be a bad idea for the young and/or unwary. Lack of polymorphic destructors and the risk of slicing.

1. Polymorphic destructors

There is actually no reasonable use case for *owning* a std container through a pointer to its base class. Containers are lightweight (when there is nothing in them) and cheaply moveable. You may be able to think of use cases, but I can guarantee that whatever you intended to do can be done better by encapsulating the container in another heap-allocated object. In well-designed code, this should never have become a concern. In any case, inheriting privately from the `priority_queue` template class removes this risk.

2. Slicing

Certainly there is a risk of slicing when we pass inherited objects around. The answer here is to inherit privately from the `priority_queue` base class, and then use `using` in the derived class to export only the parts of the base class's interface that we wish to share.

The example below has been updated to show this.

Below is an example from a real project.

Requirements: 
Keep a queue of topics that a client must be notified changes to. Order the queue by the timestamp of the earliest time that this topic was notified. Do not allow duplicate topic names.

Here is a working demo:

```
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

using topic_type = std::string;
using timestamp_clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
using timestamp_type = timestamp_clock::time_point;

struct notification {
    topic_type topic;
    timestamp_type timestamp;
};

bool topic_equals(const notification& l, const topic_type& r) {
    return l.topic == r;
}
bool topic_equals(const topic_type& l, const notification& r) {
    return l == r.topic;
}

bool age_after(const notification& l , const notification& r) {
    return l.timestamp > r.timestamp;
}

bool age_after(const notification& l , const timestamp_type& r) {
    return l.timestamp > r;
}

bool age_after(const timestamp_type& l , const notification& r) {
    return l > r.timestamp;
}

struct greater_age
{
    template<class T, class U>
    bool operator()(const T& l, const U& r) const {
        return age_after(l, r);
    }
};

template<class T>
struct pending_queue_traits;

template<>
struct pending_queue_traits<notification>
{
    using container_type = std::vector<notification>;
    using predicate_type = greater_age;
    using type = std::priority_queue<notification, container_type, predicate_type>;
};

class pending_notification_queue
: private pending_queue_traits<notification>::type
{
    using traits_type = pending_queue_traits<notification>;
    using base_class = traits_type::type;

public:


    // export the constructor
    using base_class::base_class;

    // and any other members our clients will need
    using base_class::top;
    using base_class::pop;
    using base_class::size;

    bool conditional_add(topic_type topic, timestamp_type timestamp = timestamp_clock::now())
    {
        auto same_topic = [&topic](auto& x) { return topic_equals(topic, x); };
        auto i = std::find_if(std::begin(c), std::end(c), same_topic);
        if (i == std::end(c)) {
            this->push(notification{std::move(topic), std::move(timestamp)});
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if (timestamp < i->timestamp) {
                i->timestamp = std::move(timestamp);
                reorder();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

private:
    void reorder() {
        std::make_heap(std::begin(c), std::end(c), comp);
    }
};

// attempt to steal only the base class...
void try_to_slice(pending_queue_traits<notification>::type naughty_slice)
{
    // danger lurks here
}
int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    auto pn = pending_notification_queue();

    auto now = timestamp_clock::now();
    pn.conditional_add("bar.baz", now);
    pn.conditional_add("foo.bar", now + 5ms);
    pn.conditional_add("foo.bar", now + 10ms);
    pn.conditional_add("foo.bar", now - 10ms);

    // assert that there are only 2 notifications
    assert(pn.size() == 2);
    assert(pn.top().topic == "foo.bar");
    pn.pop();
    assert(pn.top().topic == "bar.baz");
    pn.pop();

    // try to slice the container. these expressions won't compile.
//    try_to_slice(pn);
//    try_to_slice(std::move(pn));

}
```

Comment: Is it not, generally, a bad idea to inherit from STL containers (even container adapters as is the case with `std::priority_queue`) due to issues with destruction? (i.e. STL containers have non-virtual destructors)

Comment: In general, I would agree. People should be wary of inheriting from containers, And relying on their polymorphic destruction is certainly an error. However, those protected members are there in priority_queue specifically for this use case. We could go further actually and argue that there is not a valid use case for allocating a container directly on the heap with new, in which case polymorphic destruction will never be needed.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury great comment - I have addressed it in the updated answer. Its interesting to see how often in the c++ community the idea of `doing this has some caveats` becomes `never, ever do this, ever!`. Senior developers can sometimes be lazy when explaining things to junior ones :)

Comment: I see, that makes sense, +1

Answer (score 4):

The stl's containers don't provide as fast as possible updatable priority queues.

@Richard Hodges: `make_heap` takes O(n) complexity, and the `push_heap` function doesn't tell you where the provided element was stored, making a quick update of a single element impossible (you need O(n) to find it).

I have implemented a high-performance updatable priority queue (an update costs O(log n), twice as fast as using an `std::set`) and made it available [on github](https://github.com/Ten0/updatable_priority_queue).

This is how you would typically use it :

```
better_priority_queue::updatable_priority_queue<int,int> pQ;
pQ.push(0, 30);   // or pQ.set(0, 30)
pQ.push(1, 20);
pQ.push(2, 10);

pQ.update(2, 25); // or pQ.set(2, 25)

while(!pQ.empty())
    std::cout << pQ.pop_value().key << ' ';

// Outputs: 0 2 1
```