# Does changing a priority queue element result in resorting the queue?

Tags: c++, stl, queue, priority-queue

I have a priority_queue, and I want to modify some of it's contents (the priority value), will the queue be resorted then?

It depends if it resorts on push/pop (more probable, becouse you just need to "insert", not resort whole), or when accessing top or pop.

I really want to change some elements in the queue. Something like that:

```
priority_queue<int> q;

int a=2,b=3,c=5;
int *ca=&a, *cb=&b, cc=&c;

q.push(a);
q.push(b);
q.push(c); //q is now {2,3,5}

*ca=4;

//what happens to q?
// 1) {3,4,5}
// 2) {4,2,5}
// 3) crash
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`priority_queue` copies the values you push into it. Your assignment at the end there will have zero effect on the order of the priority queue, nor the values stored inside of it.

Comment: `make_heap` hack? If you use `make_heap`, and then change data in the heap, it should work fine so long as the new value maintains the same ordering as the old value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810190/how-to-tell-a-stdpriority-queue-to-refresh-its-ordering?rq=1 check it out.

Comment: what if it's int* being pushed in, and we use customized comparison method to compare the int value the pointer point to.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the `std::priority_queue` class doesn't support the `increase/decrease_key` operations that you're looking for. Of course it's possible to find the element within the heap you want to update, and then call `make_heap` to restore the binary heap invariants, but this can't be done as efficiently as it should be with the `std::` container/algorithms. Scanning the heap to find the item is `O(N)` and then `make_heap` is `O(N)` on top of that - it should be possible to do `increase/decrease_key` in `O(log(N))` for binary heaps that properly support updates.

Boost provides a [set of priority queue implementations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/heap.html), which are potentially more efficient than the `std::priority_queue` (pairing heaps, Fibonacci heaps, etc) and also offer mutability, so you can efficiently perform dynamic updates. So all round, using the boost containers is potentially a much better option.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after searching a bit I found out how to "resort" queue, so after each priority value change you need to call:

```
std::make_heap(const_cast<Type**>(&queue.top()),
     const_cast<Type**>(&queue.top()) + queue.size(),
     ComparerClass());
```

And queue must be then

```
std::priority_queue<Type*,vector<Type*>,ComparerClass> queue;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not clear if the standard allows for this, though it appears to work on some existing implementations.

Comment: Performing a total `make_heap` on the entire queue just because you changed the priority of a single element will be catastrophically inefficient. It will work, but it has very little practical value.

Comment: I thinks that in some cases, like in Dijkstra's algorithm, it is possible re push the changed value

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this issue while considering the use of priority queues for an A* algorithm.

Basically, C++ priority queues are a very limited toy.

Dynamically changing the priority of a queued element requires to perform a complete reconstruction of the underlying heap manually, which is not even guaranteed to work on a given STL implementation ***and*** is grossly inefficient.
Besides, reconstructing the heap requires butt-ugly code, which would have to be hidden in yet another obfuscated class/template.

As for so many other things in C++, you'll have to reinvent the wheel, or find whatever fashionable library that reinvented it for you.