# Updating Priority Queue Order On Element Changes

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I have found some similar questions on this subject, but I wanted to ask again in order to get a more clear answer. I am writing a graph matching algorithm, where each node on the graph assigned to a priority set depending on the matching of its neighbours. Details are not really important, but I am using an **std::priority_queue** in order to match the highest priority nodes first. Here is the tricky point: Each time a new match is introduced, the priority of the neighbours of the matching nodes shall be updated.

This algorithm is referenced from a paper and although I have implemented the exact same algorithm, I couldn't reach the same matching percentage. I naturally suspected that **std::priority_queue** may not be reordered as I wanted on priority updates, so I have run some tests and then I found out other questions asking the same thing:

[How to tell a std::priority_queue to refresh its ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810190/how-to-tell-a-stdpriority-queue-to-refresh-its-ordering/5810342)

[Does changing a priority queue element result in resorting the queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016189/does-changing-a-priority-queue-element-result-in-resorting-the-queue?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My question naturally is, how can I update the order on new matchings? Can I enforce it? Or is there any other data structure (max heap for example) that can serve to this purpose? Note that, pushing new elements into the queue is not a valid solution for me. Here is the code piece I am using (matchFace() function updates the element priorities):

```
while (priorityQueue.size() != 0) {

    // Take the face at the top of the queue and check if it is already matched
    FaceData* currentFace = priorityQueue.top();

    // Pop the face at the top in any case
    priorityQueue.pop();

    // If the face is not already matched, try to find a matching
    if (!currentFace->matched) {

        // Try to match the face with one of its neighbors, add it to the unmatched faces list if it fails
        int neighborId = matchFace(currentFace);
        if (neighborId == -1) {
            unmatchedFaces.push_back(currentFace);
        } else {
            matchingMap[currentFace->id] = neighborId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you remove the affected elements from the queue, change them, and add them back in?

Comment: Ok nevermind it's not possible to do that with a std::priority_queue. You'll probably have to write this own. In this case a priority_queue might not be the right tool for the job. Could you explain the broader problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe I can do an iterative search using node ids but it is very inefficient. I am trying to find the maximum matching on a dual graph, where each node is assigned to a priority set from 0 to 3. As nodes get matched, the priority of their neighbours shall be updated so that the one with the highest priority will be matched first. This way, the node with less number of free neighbours will be given priority on the matching.

Comment: You could probably fabricate what you want with the heap mechanics included in the C++ standard library. Essentially you would make the initial heap within a vector, then process it like a priority queue, but manage the neighbors in the "queue" by removing them, updating their priority, then pushing them back into the heap. The removal is the only tricky part, as you can/will introduce a "hole" in your sequence, which must be sewn up by taking the *last* element in the remaining heap, moving it to the hole, then running a heap-down op from there down to re-cinch up the heap.

Comment: Boost's `binomial_heap` allows you to update an element and re-order it within the queue.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently, and what I ended up doing was inheriting from priority_queue (usual "no user serviceable parts" warnings here). I added a public method that called std::make_heap() on the underlying collection (a std::vector in my case). I called this method when the priority of other elements had changed. It's not pretty, but it works in my situation.

Comment: I thought the standard C++ library would have a data structure for that. Thank you for all the answers, I'll try and choose the best suited if I don't get back any other answer. Maybe Java has a better solution to that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the comments that I received on the problem, I decided to answer it myself. I found out there are three possible ways to overcome this problem:

- Implement your own updatable priority queue or use external libraries. Boost might have some additional data structures for this purpose. I also found an [Updatable Priority Queue](http://jamesgregson.blogspot.com/2010/02/updateable-priority-queue.html) source code here.
- Use a vector to store the values and use [std::make_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) function provided in the algorithm library each time an update is received. This is the easiest way but it works very slow.
- Remove and re-insert the elements. If this is not a valid approach, use a map to store the element ids and instead of removing the elements, mark the elements on the map so if you encounter them multiple times you can just ignore them. An alternative strategy is to alter the items by adding a flag and marking the elements by turning the flag on.