# C++ Priority Queue - Reorder based on updated priorities

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, data-structures, priority-queue

Some background: I am building a `C++` thread manager which allows the user to create an `AsyncJob` object and assign a priority of execution. I have a `JobManager` singleton class which manages a priority queue of these `AsyncJobs` and assigns them to a thread when available.

The Problem: Users need to be able to modify the priority `AFTER` creation. For instance, based on some run-time events, a file may need to be loaded more urgently than others. The issue I am facing is that priority queues only reorder elements on the internal heap when `push()` or `pop()` is called. There is no exposed interface, to my knowledge, that allows one to request a reorder based on changing priorities.

What I would like to do is something like this:

- Create a `hashmap` in my `JobManager` class which holds pointers to objects in the priority queue
- User can access a requested job by its key and update the priority through the hash map
- The `JobManager` then signals to the priority queue that priorities have changed
- Priority queue reorders itself internally

What would be the best way of going about this? Should I expect to make my own custom priority queue class? Or maybe extend from the `std::priority_queue`?

Thanks!

Comment: How frequent are these changes? Can priorities go up and down, or just up, or just down? I doubt that `std::priority_queue` will do what you want, but if I know a bit more about what your setup looks like I can try to point you in the right direction.

Comment: The changes will most likely be up; However up and down are both valid.  The priority updates will not be that frequent.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/q/649640/56778, you're out of luck with `std::priority_queue`. You'll have to implement your own or find one that'll do it.

Comment: See "How to do an efficient priority update in STL priority_queue?"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649640/how-to-do-an-efficient-priority-update-in-stl-priority-queue?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to allow your AsyncJob to have a 'cancelled' state, and simply add a new (copy of) the AsyncJob to your PQ each time the priority is modified, after cancelling the old one.

As with many things, I'd suggest that 'best way' is highly subjective, as it depends on how constrained you are, and how you quantify 'best'.     Personally I like to avoid deriving from standard library types and re-inventing container structures if possible.

Comment: For infrequent updates, this seems like a great idea.

Comment: Sometimes the simple solution is the best. I have to remind myself premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 2):

A [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) seems like a decent alternative.

The binary search tree should be ordered by priority and, secondly, if priority isn't unique, a unique identifier / set of identifiers in the object.

If you don't know the previous priority when you want to change it, you'll need a way to look that up - perhaps a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) of object to priority.

This allows you to remove and reinsert a specific item in `O(log n)`, without losing the `O(log n)` performance on other operations (and `O(1)` to get the first).

---

For C++:

If priority is unique, a [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) of priority to object could work, otherwise a [`set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)`<`[`pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)`>` where the first element in the pair is the priority, and the second is the object (yes, I know, those aren't necessarily BST's).

For the hash table, you could use an [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) of object to priority, or simply a `map` pre-C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Removing an item that changed its priority and then adding it (or a copy, if the new priority logically means a new item) is probably the easiest way. After all, you don't want to reorder the entire queue from scratch, just the single changed item - removing it and inserting it will do that.

EDIT: However, as Paul Renton mentioned, `std::priority_queue` doesn't allow getting individual items without poppinh the head, so I'd then roll my own priority queue using `std::vector` with inspiration from `std::priority_queue`, which uses `std::vector` by default. I would *only* expose what I need, not the entire API set of `std::priority_queue`. Instead of *resorting* the whole list, I'd allow removing and inserting an item correctly sorted by priority.

Comment: The problem is I can't access the element in the priority queue with iteration. I believe the only way to get elements from the pqueue is with a call to top()

Comment: Ahh, right, of course - you can only get items out of `std::priority_queue` by popping... Then I'd roll my own priority queue using `std::vector` with inspiration from `std::priority_queue`, which uses `std::vector` by default. I would *only* expose what I need, not the entire API set of `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: @PaulRenton: Edited my answer to reflect your comment.